# В какой JS проект войти для получения опыта

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Обучаюсь js, знаю немного питон. Хотелось бы узнать где найти js проекты которым требуется помощь, или где можно просто поучаствовать ("зацепиться за вагон"). Сам пока могу jQuery, простые google расширения, немного phoneGap. Опыт нужен именно в js, пусть хоть простенький рефакторинг и то +.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучший опыт - свой проект. Сформулируйте задачи и вперед. Мекка проектов > [Github](https://github.com/trending?l=javascript). Огромное количество библиотек и приложений. Открытое сообщество и открытый код. Можно изучать подходы, стили кодирования и участвовать в разработке.

Comment: дополню: один из, по-моему, наилучших способов «вникнуть» (в логику работы, в используемый язык программирования и т.п.) — это помощь в исправлении ошибок.

Answer (score -1):

Свой проект это самое правильное решение.

1. Вы будете знать все тонкости и нюансы.
2. Мотивации больше(Это как по мне)
3. И в случаи завершения проекта вы сможете положить в портфолио